# Soft body for a round character

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices, soft-body

I wanted to give a try to create and animated a character i made back in the day and there's a few thing i would like to know to make easier to create it.

I completed the body with a few problems with the edges which i can take an idea.
Where i would like to know is if there's an easier way to "soft" the body to look like almost a perfect sphere instead of use the proportional editing everytime on each vertice or using sculpt.

PSD: The pike on the third image is intentionall. Last images on sculpt mode to clarify( need the body to be smoother like a round sphere)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `To Sphere` transformation to make sets of vertices more nearly spherical: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/to_sphere.html

You can also use `Smooth Vertex` to smooth out sets of vertices, as unintended jaggedness is a common problem when trying to achieve smooth features in a complex mesh:

https://blenderartists.org/t/is-there-a-way-to-smooth-out-the-vertices-in-blender/518443

I would, however, add this: when a key feature of a primitive form (like sphericity) is desired, it is usually best to start from a primitive (like, well, a sphere) that already has that form, and only gradually modify those features of it that you don't want to maintain. Working in the opposite direction (complex form to primitive features) is often considerably more difficult.

Comment: Thanks! I tried with the to sphere option, it smooths well the form. I know that  i should have started with a simple sphere and on my case open it wide but it would cost me a bit when adding the eyelid so i started with them and then extrude to get the form. Thought that would be easier to get the form. But besides it works better now.

Answer (score 0):

are you referring to "Shade Smooth"?

In Object Mode Select your character > "Object" Tab > "Shade Smooth"

Let me know!

Comment: No, i mean more like make the mesh without deformations that make the look ugly and not almost spherical at all. When i try with the shade smooth it show better the shape that it´s not smooth. What i want is that the mesh has a look like it comes directly from an undeformed sphere don´t know if im clear.

Comment: I apologize, but I'm having trouble visualizing this. Are you able to post images of the look you want (through some references on google)

Comment: Right now my character has like small deformation. In summary, it is not 100 percent round in a clean way. I want it to be like the Monoculus from Tf2.       I'll link this to clarify more: https://wiki.teamfortress.com/w/images/thumb/1/1f/Monoculus_normal.png/300px-Monoculus_normal.png